# how to redirect www.xyz.com/webmail to mail.xyz.com through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$

RewriteRule ^webmail$ "http\:\/\/mail\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

But Above code in .htaccess is not working however given below code is working

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^folderName\/$ "http\:\/\/www\.domain\.net\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Depending on the link you provide you _might_ be successful with changing the pattern to `^webmail/?$`. That way a trailing slash is accepted too.

Comment: one more thing i want to know that .htaccess file would be public_html folder or outside it or under folder of domain name

Comment: As i know that webmail is not a folder

Comment: _Most likely_ you have to place that `.htaccess` style file inside the `public_html` folder. But obviously that depends on the setup of the system which only you know about.

Comment: If `webmail` is a folder or does exist at all in the file system is irrelevant here. Rewriting is performed long before the file system is consulted at all.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xyz.com
RewriteRule ^webmail/(.*)$ http://mail.xyz.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

EDIT:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^webmail/(.*) http://mail.xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hmm I've added an edit to see if that helps. Thanks for input into answer guys.